# Python django Foreign Key Relationships problem

Tags: python, django, relational-database

I am working on an online school project, where I got classes, and in the classes I have different subjects, I added a one-to-many(ForeignKey) Relation between "Classes" and "Subjects", but when it comes the view theme on the HTML page Subjects from 2.Class comes to show on 1.Class one page(all Subjects are showed in one class)

**How to Fix this problem??**
**(How to keep 2.Class Subjects in the 2.Class page as well for 1.Class?)**

**MY CODE**

***viws.py***

```
def classes(request):
    classes = Class.objects
    context={
        'class':classes
    }
    return render(request, "templates/Classes.html", context)

def subjects(request, sub_id):
    classes=get_object_or_404(Class, pk=sub_id)
    subject=Subject.objects.all()
    context={
        'classes':classes,
        'subject':subject
    }
    return render(request, "templates/Subjects.html", context)
```

***Models.py***

```
class Class(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to="images")

class Subject(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    Class=models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Webpage**

```
{%for subject in subject.all%}
<div class="cardrow">
    <div class="cardcolumn">
        <a href="#"> 
            <div class="card">
                <h1>{{subject.title}}</h1>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>         
</div>
{%endfor%}
```

So again all subjects are showing in one class. tho I added a Foreign Key relationship

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You get all, because you're asking for `all` contents of `Subject`.

This is how you can get all subjects related to a class:

```
subjects = class_obj.subject_set.all()
```

Also see the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: I did that but I got this error `'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'`

Comment: Sorry just updated the answer you need to do it on the instance. I got confused, since you're using Class/class as variables/properties too.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have them all displayed because you simply fetching all `Subjects` from DB and showing them on page. You need to filter `Subjects` using, as an option, `subject_id` you're passing to the view:

```
def subjects(request, sub_id):
    class_obj=get_object_or_404(Class, pk=sub_id)
    subject=Subject.objects.filter(Class_id=class_obj)
    context={
        'classes':class_obj,
        'subjects':subject
    }
```

and then in template:

```
{% for subject in subjects %}
```

Next thing is that view parameter named `sub_id` is actually a class ID - better to rename it.

And one more thing (among other) is that it's bad practice to shadow build-in names like you did by naming model fields as `Class`. And yes, it should be lowercase.